# xamarin sqlite SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error add

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am trying to learn xaml and C# used in Xamarin Forms, and now I want to implement SQLite functionality.
I am simply trying to add a value into a SQL table but get the following error:

Unhandled Exception:

SQLite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error occurred

My Database connection interface is as follows:

```
using SQLite;
namespace TestSQLite
{
    public interface IDatabaseConnection
    {
        SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection();
    }
}
```

My Android specific Database Connection (iOS is identical) is as follows:

```
using SQLite;
using System.IO;
using TestSQLite; 
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DatabaseConnection))]

namespace TestSQLite
{
    public class DatabaseConnection : IDatabaseConnection
    {
        public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection() 
        {
            var dbName = "TestDb.db3";
            var path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), dbName);

            return new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
        }
    }
}
```

My MainPage (testpage) is as follows:

```
using SQLite;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestSQLite
{
    public class ControlledDrugs
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Drug { get; set; }
        public double Volume { get; set; }
    }
    public class Users
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _connection = DependencyService.Get<IDatabaseConnection>().GetConnection();
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            await _connection.CreateTableAsync<ControlledDrugs>();
            await _connection.CreateTableAsync<Users>();

            var drugs = await _connection.Table<ControlledDrugs>().ToListAsync();
            Drugslistview.ItemsSource = drugs;

            var user = await _connection.Table<Users>().ToListAsync();
            Userlistview.ItemsSource = user;

            base.OnAppearing();
        }
        async void OnAdd(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var user = UserInput.Text;
//The next step generates the error
            await _connection.InsertAsync(user);
        }

        void OnUpdate(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        void OnDelete(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

As you can see, I have yet to progress to update or delete. Learning by Youtube and Stackoverflow snippets is painfully slow. But this error got me stumped.
Also, have NuGet package sqlite-net-pcl v1.5.166-beta installed Xamarin Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are attempting to insert a string into the User table instead of a User object

```
var user = UserInput.Text;
// user is just a string
await _connection.InsertAsync(user);
```

instead you need to create a User object

```
var user = new Users { Name = UserInput.Text };
await _connection.InsertAsync(user);
```

Comment: Thank you Jason, I hope that one day I'll have enough experience to pay it forward.

Comment: Oh dear, next issue: the button click no longer shows an error, but the "Names" are not showing on the list view. However, there are definitely database entries happening because blank entries appear in the list view.
Seems I am saving blank each time.

Comment: please post a new question